# DirectShow Rotate Filter with an EVR output

Tags: windows, video, directshow

I'm using the only rotate filter I've found several versions of, originally from SourceForge, now I found it hosted on github: https://github.com/CSIR-RTVC/RotateFilter. It works fine when used with the default DShow renderer, however when I use it with an EVR renderer the image comes out as garbled. The width and height are correct, but the image looks like it's missing a stride or something:

[image]

vs the original (but rotated):

[image]

I've tried debugging it and the format seems to be accepted, both the input and output pins are RGB32, the automatic pin connections are made seemingly correctly, the graph seems fine, but the output is garbled.

[image]

Any ideas what could be going on with EVR in particular?

Comment: How do you use the EVR? If you render on a Direct3D surface you could just rotate this surface.

Comment: I created an Dshow EVR object and added it to my graph, as you can see in the pink screenshot above. Are you saying I can customize the rendering part? How?

Comment: This is just testing the graph. How is the EVR used in your application? As the output of the EVR can be rendered on a Direct3D surface you can customize how it is displayed. (Rotated/mirrored/...)

Comment: The visual effect suggests that the filter does not handle stride extension and uploads image to texture with no account for required padding. The solution is also obvious - to update the filter source code and correct the paddnig behavior. Some related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22extended+stride%22

Comment: Source code reference https://github.com/CSIR-RTVC/RotateFilter/blob/master/RotateFilter.cpp#L232 where the comments give an idea that the code might need some further improvement.

Comment: @RomanR. I did see those comments, but it's not entirely clear to me what the fix is. Like at all. That's because the buffer to write into comes from DShow itself, and it's already allocated to the same size as the input buffer, I can't write more data into it with this extended stride. I also have no idea where to get the extended stride, the only stride I see in code is a guess at the end.

Comment: I can understand the confusion, yet the resolution path remains the same. The mechanism requires a bit more of understanding that I can put into comment at the moment. The idea is that EVR informs that there will be extended stride https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/handling-format-changes-from-the-video-renderer and the allocator is supposed to get updated respectively. Upstream filter will use the new stride when it's time to process new samples and would add the padding. Or otherwise the filter can indicate correctly that it won't support non-standard stride.

Comment: I did read that but most of the `QueryAccept` stuff is hidden deep inside the MS base classes. Are you saying I need to edit them somewhere? Can you provide a working example of this, or point to at least the part of the code that I need to change, and where to get this extended stride from?